# Firebase Realtime database Element is unexpectedly nil (Swift)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please let me know if this is a repeat, I've seen a lot of similar questions. I'm running into a problem where I'm able to retrieve most data in my database inside of calls to RunTransactionBlock and ObserveSingleEvent, but when I try to retrieve nested data it gives me a value of nil.

I know that wording is a bit unclear, but here's an example of what exactly is happening:

This is the current state of
[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rgQp.png)

And here is a section of my code (newGame is a reference to the dynamically created element of Games):

```
global.newGame.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
        if var state = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            var player0Info = state["player0Info"] as? [String : AnyObject]
            var hand = player0Info?["Hand"] as? Array<String> 
            var name = player0Info?["Name"] as? String
            var playerNum = player0Info?["PlayerNum"] as? Int
            var score = player0Info?["Score"] as? Int
            var thingToGet = player0Info?["ThingToGet"] as? [String : AnyObject]
            print(hand!)
            print(name!)
            print(playerNum!)
            print(score!)
            print(thingToGet)
            //Code to modify data
            //...
            currentData.value = state
        }
      return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
      if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
```

Which gives me an output of

```
["card1", "card2", "card3"]
Jeff
0
0
nil
```

Why am I not able to access ThingToGet in this scenario? The same thing happens when I use ObserveSingleEvent instead of a transaction, and even though the data clearly exists in the database, I can't seem to do anything to make it not show up as nil.

Side note: I know that I'm not supposed to use arrays in firebase, I'm working on getting rid of that.

Update: There's a piece of my code that I left out that is causing the problem. In order to add the component if it doesn't already exist, I have this block of code

```
if thingToGet == nil {
    thingToGet = ["0": ["sampleInfo"]] as [String : AnyObject]
}
player0Info["ThingToGet"] = thingToGet as AnyObject
state["Player0Info"] = player0Info as AnyObject
CurrentData.value = state
```

And this is what's causing my problem. Everything gets written to the database correctly, but for some reason when this executes when ThingToGet is not nil, it always gives me a value of nil. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Someone please correct me if there is a better solution than this, but here's what I did to get it working.

I changed

```
var thingToGet = player0Info?["ThingToGet"] as? [String : AnyObject]
```

to

```
var thingToGet = player0Info?["ThingToGet"]
```

And I changed

```
thingToGet = ["0": ["sampleInfo"]] as [String : AnyObject]
```

to

```
thingToGet = ["0": ["sampleInfo"]] as [String : AnyObject] as AnyObject
```

And now everything is working as expected.